# Maintaining a static list of shared_ptr for multiple class instances

Tags: c++

**Problem Summary:**

What is the proper way to keep a static list of shared_ptr for different instances of a class, be able to get the class instance from a free function and manage the deconstruction of the instances and list?

**Objective:**

Say I have a device class, I expect to instantiate a couple of instances each corresponding to a different property type (eg. keyboard, mouse or pen). I'd then like to have a free function grab the class instance by passing the property type to a static get_instance method.

```
class Device {
public:
    typedef enum class Type_t {
        Keyboard = 0,
        Mouse,
        Pen
    };

    Device(std::string const & instance, Type_t type);
    ~ Device();
    Type_t getType() { return itsType;}

    static void get_instance(std::shared_ptr<Device> & inst, Type_t type);
private:
    Type_t itsType;
};
```

**How I currently approached it:**

I keep global list of shared_ptr

```
static std::list< std::shared_ptr<Device> > gDeviceInstances;
```

that I append when instantiating

```
gDeviceInstances.push_back(std::make_shared<Device>("Pen",Device::Type_t::Pen));
```

then retrieve the instance from a free function

```
void freefunction(void){
    std::shared_ptr<Device> m;
    Device::get_instance(m, Device::Type_t::Pen);
    m->DoSomething();
}
```

where

```
void Device::get_instance(std::shared_ptr<Device> & inst, Device::Type_t type) {
    for (auto & s : (gDeviceInstances)){
        if (s->getType() == type) { inst = s;}}
    if (inst == nullptr) {
        std::cout<< "No matching Device Class instance" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

This works, but I'm not sure how to manage the deconstructor. The smart_ptr is automatically deleted, corrupting the list. And if I remove the instance from the list manually I get an error as well, as the program is trying to remove the smart_ptr.

```
Device::~Device() {

    std::cout<< "Destructing a device" << std::endl;
    for (auto & s : (gDeviceInstances)){
        if (Type_t (s->getType()) == itsType) {
            gDeviceInstances.remove(s);
        }
    }
```

Also, if I wanted to manage the class instance list within the class, and append the list inside the class constructor, say something like

```
class Device : public std::enable_shared_from_this<Device > {
    public:
    ..
    static std::list< std::shared_ptr<Device > > itsInstances;
    ..
    ..

}; 

std::list< std::shared_ptr<Device > > itsInstances; //Static members must be defined

Device ::Device (std::string const &instance, Type_t type): itsType(type) {

    itsInstances.push_back(shared_from_this());
}
```

How can it be done properly?

Comment: Unrelated to your problem and question, but the "go to" container that you should use by default should be `std::vector`. Only use one of the others, or a container adapter, if you have special requirements.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude One thing about `list` in this application is that you can keep an iterator to your own entry in the list and remove yourself in constant time and without invalidating any other entry in the list.

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood but it looks to me like you are relying on the `Device`'s destructor to remove it's own entry in the list. If that's the case, your destructor will never be called because a `shared_ptr` will always exist, thus the "last" `shared_ptr` to the instance is never destroyed. Have you considered using a list of [`weak_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr) instead?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux If one needs to store iterators to elements, then that's part of the "special requirements" I would say. :)

Comment: Note that `shared_from_this()` doesn't work in the constructor. The object has to have been completely constructed and `std::make_shared` must have returned before you can use it.

Comment: What is the point of having `Device::get_instance()` accept a reference to `std::shared_ptr<Device>` for the purposes of populating it instead of just returning `std::shared_ptr<Device>`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, good point, I just kept it inline with an existing code implementation I'm extending.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux, Re first comment, I used a map instead as suggested in an answer below, I can safely reset the device entry it seems. Re 2nd comment: That makes sense, that I need to construct it first.

Comment: @cdhowie, correct, I initially thought I'm not doing a proper shared_ptr copy.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**:  Removed wrapper suggestion.

---

First, use an `std::map<type, shared_ptr>` instead of a list.  You can check if an item exists using `map::find(type) != map::end()`, but since shared_ptr is null by default, you could probably just return `map[type]` and if it doesn't exist, then shared_ptr will be null.

Deleting a Device is just assigning an empty `shared_ptr` to its `map` slot:  `map[type] = shared_ptr<Device>()`

---

Also, don't return `shared_ptr`, return `weak_ptr`. Weak Pointers are meant to point at objects that can be deleted out from under them. Just check `weak_ptr<Device>.expired()` before `weak_ptr<Device>.lock()`ing to a shared_ptr.

---

And the Final piece:

Don't let Shared Pointer Delete `this`.

```
// specify a delete functor that does nothing, this creates a non-owning shared_ptr
    mThisSharedPtr = SharedPtr(this,   /*NoDeleteFunc*/ [](DisplayObject*) {});
```

---

`typedef` is your friend.  It can turn `std::shared_ptr<Device>` into `SharedDevicePtr` or `std::map<type,SharedDevicePtr>` into `SharedDeviceMap`, etc...

Comment: instead of returning nullprt, throw an exception

Comment: I used map instead, it does make more sense. And it is easier to remove device from the map without having to iterate. I did change get_instance to return a weak_ptr but I have a question, if I'm already returning a shared_ptr in a closed scope how is it different from returning a weak_ptr and lock()ing to shared_ptr, again in closed local scope. In both cases, my shared_ptr count will be incremented only temporarily. Is it just safer, in case get_instance is called in a location that would allow the shared_ptr to go out of scope?

Comment: No, no, no, no! Using `expired()` this way is inherently unsafe! There is no guarantee that the pointed-to object won't be deleted between your calls to `expired()` and `lock()` -- this is a race condition. At best, the `expired()` test adds no value and at worst you are setting yourself up for UB when you dereference a null pointer. The correct pattern is `auto strongPtr = weakPtr.lock(); if (strongPtr) { /* have object */ } else { /* object was deleted /* }`

Comment: Your `Device* get() const` implementation is also unsafe because it returns a `T*` which could be deleted by another thread. You **must** access these objects through a `shared_ptr`. That is the only way that you can be absolutely sure the object won't be deleted out from under you while you are using it. There is very little in your answer that *doesn't* set up whomever uses it for a terrible night of debugging due to a race condition.

Comment: My apologies.  I seem to be missing the thread-safe requirement in the original question.

Comment: Btw, this entire class top to bottom isn't thread safe. It's interesting that people would bemoan locking a pointer as unsafe and completely miss unsynchronized access to stl containers.  If you are worried about thread safety, I'm afraid that's a whole other question.

Comment: I'm bemoaning that because it's an anti-pattern that I see on a regular basis -- and the `expired()` checks add no value even in a single-threaded environment. So your suggestion to *"check `weak_ptr<Device>.expired()` before `weak_ptr<Device>.lock()`ing to a shared_ptr"* is still pointless. Just `lock()` and check if the `shared_ptr` is truthy. `expired()` is only useful when you want to check if the `weak_ptr` points to an object *without doing anything with the object.* If you are going to use the object if it's there, just use `lock()`.